# cannot insert document into mongodb collection node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am very new to `mongodb`, literally just installed yesterday. I created a collection programmatically, and now am trying to insert a document into the already created collection.

here's what I have:

```
 MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
   if (err) throw err;
     db.socialPosts.insert( { title: "My First Post", description: "This is my first post desc" } )
     console.log("success")
     db.close();
  });
});
```

the name of the `collection` is `socialPosts`, and I am just trying to insert a doc into it. The error it is throwing is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: the variable `db` that you have declared its a `client` object, you can access db as per your declared variable `db.db('dbName').socialPosts.insert(` or `db.db.socialPosts.insert(`, refer [mongodb docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the answers above, and some research online, I have come across this solution:

```
client.connect().then (() => {
const database = client.db("myFirstDatabase");
const socialPosts = database.collection("socialPosts");

MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    const doc = { title: postTitle, description: postDescription, instagramLink: instagramLink };
    socialPosts.insertOne(doc)
    db.close();
    });
});
```

this works seamlessly :)